# How to determine packet loss when pinging a website

Tags: networking, ping

When pinging and or tracerouting a website how can I determine whether the website actually has packet loss or its a firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no packets reach the destination, there are several possible situations:

- An IP address that is not assigned to anything. Depending on the configuration of the last reachable router, you might get a "destination/host/net unreachable" [error message](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-121-mainline/12778-ping-traceroute.html).
- An IP address that is assigned to a machine, but ping is blocked by a firewall. Depending on the configuration, some firewalls will might drop the packets silently, others will return an "administratively prohibited" error message.
- An IP address that is assigned to a machine, ping is not blocked but the machine is down.  Depending on the configuration of the last reachable router, you might get a "destination/host/net unreachable" [error message](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-121-mainline/12778-ping-traceroute.html).

If some packets go through: a firewall usually either allows all your traffic or blocks it; it shouldn't let through just some of the packets, unless it limits the number of probes. So if you see intermittent loss, it's probably not a firewall, although you cannot exclude it with 100% certainty.

If some packets go through and for others you get the "unreachable" messages, there is either a firewall that limits a certain number of ping packets per second, or a routing problem (load balancing and one path fails; or route flapping).

If some packets go through and for others you get no reply, it's probably packet loss. Could be a link problem, such as a wireless link or a congested link; or it could be a routing problem. Less likely, it is a firewall that limits the number of ICMP packets.

Also keep in mind that ping uses ICMP, while traceroute uses UDP by default (although it can use ICMP too with a command line option). Firewall rules might be different for the two protocols.

Comment: I focused on ping. See ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/hpcp/UDP-ICMP-Traceroutes.pdf for more details on how traceroute works.